# Can't get DynamicModule[{..},..EventHandler[] ] working

Tags: dynamic

This makes a slider to control the number of points. Click in the `Graphics` and the points slide over to where you click.

```
Manipulate[
DynamicModule[{points,oldPoints,centerG,oldCenterG,finalPnts,mousePosn},
points=Map[{10,12}+#&,Table[{Cos[2.0 Pi k/n],Sin[2.0 Pi k/n]},{k,1,n}]];
oldPoints=finalPnts=points;
oldCenterG=centerG=Mean/@Transpose[points];

Dynamic[EventHandler[Framed[Graphics[{PointSize[0.02],Point[
If[TrueQ[points==finalPnts],
oldCenterG=centerG;
oldPoints=points,
(* else *)
points=MapThread[
With[{mag=Norm[#2-#1]},If[TrueQ[mag<=0.02],#2,#1+0.04(#2-#1)/mag]]&,
{points,finalPnts}]
]
]},PlotRange->{{-15,15},{-15,15}},ImageSize->{600,600}]],
{"MouseDown":>(
mousePosn=MousePosition["Graphics"];
centerG=Mean/@Transpose[points];
finalPnts=Map[(#+mousePosn-oldCenterG)&,oldPoints]) ,
"MouseUp":>(centerG=mousePosn)
}]] 
],{{n,3},3,8,1}]
```

The problem is that my real application doesn't allow use of `Manipulate`. 
I thought the code below would work, but it breaks when you click in the `Graphics`. 
How to get the second version working?

```
DynamicModule[{points, oldPoints, centerG, oldCenterG, finalPnts, 
  mousePosn, n},

 points = 
  Dynamic[Map[{10, 12} + # &, 
    Table[{Cos[2.0 Pi k/n], Sin[2.0 Pi k/n]}, {k, 1, n}]]];
 oldPoints = finalPnts = points;
 oldCenterG = centerG = Mean /@ Transpose[points];

 Column[{
   Slider[Dynamic[n], {3, 8, 1}],
   Dynamic[EventHandler[Framed[Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Point[
         If[TrueQ[points == finalPnts],
          oldCenterG = centerG;
          oldPoints = points,
          (* else *)
          points = MapThread[

            With[{mag = Norm[#2 - #1]}, 
              If[TrueQ[mag <= 0.02], #2, #1 + 0.04 (#2 - #1)/mag]] &,
            {points, finalPnts}]
          ]
         ]}, PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}, 
       ImageSize -> {400, 400}]],
     {"MouseDown" :> (
        mousePosn = MousePosition["Graphics"];
        centerG = Mean /@ Transpose[points];
        finalPnts = Map[(# + mousePosn - oldCenterG) &, oldPoints]) ,
      "MouseUp" :> (centerG = mousePosn)
      }]]}]]
```

Comment: Ted can you explain why you can't use `Manipulate`? This can obviously be re-written as a `DynamicModule` but are you able to use that? What is causing your restrictions?

Comment: Sorry for being a pain, but I still haven't learned how to format the code. Much of the time I come here using my iPhone which has many features in stack exchange missing. Sometime when I am at home, I will try to contact one of you on chat and learn some stuff. Want my email address?

Comment: No worries, using SE from an iPhone can be a pain. One solution might be to not post long questions from an iPhone. In any case, you're always welcome to drop by our [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica) if you have any questions on the site/formatting/etc... it's usually active with some casual chatter going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I "needed to" avoid using `Manipulate` because, in my real application, the number of points in the graphic isn't controlled with a slider. The number and placement of the points is cotrolled with

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],Framed@Graphics[{}],LocatorAutoCreate->True]]
```

Well it might have been possible to get it working with `Manipulate`, but I couldn't figure it out. Anyway I figured out a way to solve the problem. I think my earlier attempt didn't work because `Head[points]` was `Dynamic`. The code below works great. Actually, in my solution below I deleted stuff that was irrelevant to the problem I was having.

```
DynamicModule[{points,points0,oldPoints,centerG,centerG0,oldCenterG,
  finalPnts,mousePosn,n},
  Column@{Slider[Dynamic[n,(
    finalPnts=points=Table[{Cos[2.0 Pi k/#],Sin[2.0 Pi k/#]},{k,1,#}];
    centerG=oldCenterG={0,0};
    n=#)&],{3,8,1}],
  Dynamic@EventHandler[Framed@Graphics[{
    Point@If[points==finalPnts,
      oldCenterG=centerG;oldPoints=points,
      (* else *)
      points=MapThread[With[{mag=Norm[#2-#1]},
         If[mag<=0.02,#2,#1+0.04(#2-#1)/mag]]&,{points,finalPnts}]
      ]},PlotRange->{{-9,9},{-9,9}}
  ],
  {"MouseDown":>(
    mousePosn=MousePosition@"Graphics";
    centerG=Mean/@Transpose@points;
    finalPnts=(#+mousePosn-oldCenterG)&/@oldPoints),
  "MouseUp":>(centerG=mousePosn)
}
]}]
```

I think it's a good illustation of programming with `Dynamic` and `EventHandler`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a `DynamicModule` version of your code. I haven't sought to modify it in any way other than to convert from `Manipulate` to `DynamicModule`:

```
DynamicModule[{points, oldPoints, centerG, oldCenterG, finalPnts, 
  mousePosn, n = 3},

 Column[{
   Manipulator[Dynamic[n], {3, 8, 1}],
   Dynamic[
   points = Map[{10, 12} + # &,Table[{Cos[2.0 Pi k/n], Sin[2.0 Pi k/n]}, {k, 1, n}]]; 
    oldPoints = finalPnts = points; 
    oldCenterG = centerG = Mean /@ Transpose[points]; 
    EventHandler[
     Framed[Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], 
        Point[If[TrueQ[points == finalPnts], oldCenterG = centerG; 
          oldPoints = points,(*else*)
          points = MapThread[With[{mag = Norm[#2 - #1]}, 
              If[TrueQ[mag <= 0.02], #2, #1 + 0.04 (#2 - #1)/mag]] &, {points, finalPnts}]]]}, 
       PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}, 
       ImageSize -> {600, 600}]], 
      {"MouseDown" :> (mousePosn = MousePosition["Graphics"]; 
        centerG = Mean /@ Transpose[points]; 
        finalPnts = Map[(# + mousePosn - oldCenterG) &, oldPoints]), 
      "MouseUp" :> (centerG = mousePosn)}]
    ]

   }]
 ]
```

**Edit**

When I posted this answer you hadn't posted your attempt. The problem with the code was that `point`, `oldpoints` and `oldCenterG` were not configured to dynamically update. Bringing them into the `Dynamic` now makes them update when `n` changes. Also you haven't given `n` a starting value whereas with your `Manipulate` you had.